# How display name of association field and not the number of active choice in easyadmin4 dashboard

Tags: field, dashboard, easyadmin, symfony6, file-type-associations

I'm working on a project symfony 6 with easyadmin4.

I have 2 entity with their repository and crud controller for easyadmin :

- 1 Entity Dish
- 1 Entity Category

All works great no errors but in the dashboard Easy Admin Display the number of category in the dish but not the Category Name.

i have search during many hours and don't find where is my problem. I have the same problem with my entity Photo who displayed the number of photo uploaded in this dish but don't see  the picture as a thunbmails like in the photo part of my admin.

[Problem in screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlOXe.png).

Tks by advance for your help

In the 2 entity i have

```
    public function __toString() {
        return $this->name;
    }
```

I have read doc about field  configuration and test different options without any result.

Answer (score 0):

In your entity controller crud you can add "AssociationField" to count the number of the fields and "ArrayField" to display the names "but in this case you shold add ->hideOnForm()", something like that:

```
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
{
    yield AssociationField::new('categories')->setFormTypeOptions(['by_reference' => false,]);
    yield ArrayField::new('categories')->hideOnForm();
}
```